# DLL file permissions causes not working

Tags: java, netbeans, dll, file-permissions

I use a dll in my Netbeans Desktop Application, loading it from */release/modules/lib* path in the module that uses it with the instruction `Native.loadLibrary(dllName, dllClass.class);`.

From the IDE all works fine, but when the application is installed, the dll doesn't works.
Making some tests I probe that changing the dll file permissions to adding it write permission, makes that the dll working fine (dll file in the installed application).
Also, executing the application with admin permissions works fine.

The target operating system is Windows (I've tested in win 7 and 10) and the install path is in c:\program files(x86).

The question is if there is a way to make from the Netbeans IDE that this dll file has this write persmission when deployed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the name of dll?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it is a custom DLL. From the IDE works fine, but doesn't when it is installed due to file permissions.

Comment: @pacobm please, can you tell, how exactly did you solved this? I have literally the exact same problem these days: native lib is accessed and loaded with no problem when I run my app from NetBeansIDE, but as soon as I export it to final JAR and try to run from the BAT file bum, my app is unable finding/loading that native lib (lwjgl64.dll)! It would really be very useful if you'd answer your own question with your solution so others like me would be able solving it too.